# ParseExact doesnt recognise a string extracted from a DataTable

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I am writing an integration test and as such, I am reading a CSV file in as a DataTable, and then trying to parse the elements in each row. However when I get a string representation of a date, and pass it into DateTime.ParseExact I get the error: "**String was not recognised as a valid DateTime**"

When I use the commented-out line in the code I provide here, and explicitly define the date as a string, then the *ParseExact* works just fine. When I debug the Integration test the *startDateString* has the correct date value.[image: Debug capture of the value from the DataTable] When it is then passed into *ParseExact* for some reason it throws an error.

I have tried to use an explicit Culture, eg. "en-GB", and DateStyles.None, without much success. Does anyone have any idea, as to why the string input I get from the DataRow is not accepted by the DateTime.ParseExact constructor?

Thanks.

```
...
var dataTable= file.ReadFile("file.csv", 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count / 2; i = i + 2) 
            {
                var startDate = new DateTime();
                var maturity= new DateTime();
                try
                {
                    var startDateString = dataTable.Rows[i]["item9"].ToString(); 
//                    var startDateString = "24/01/2008";
                    var formats = new[] { "dd/M/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" };
                    startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
                    endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dataTable.Rows[i]["item10"].ToString(), formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal); 
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new FormatException(String.Format("There was an error with the format of one of the dates in the file"));  
                }
...
```

Comment: Is it possible that the value being pulled from the "item9" column is not a date?  Have you confirmed that the value being assigned to startDateString from the datatable is what you expect?

Comment: Check what is `dataTable.Rows[i]["item10"].ToString()` and post it here

Comment: Here's the debug capture of the value that is returned from the DataRow. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you have a space at the end of the date coming from the datatable.  "24/01/2008 ".  Remove that space with a call to Trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your startDateString has a trailing space in it.

Comment: Good call!! I was working too late yesterday and, as it seems, couldn't see straight in front of me! Thanks to everyone for another pair of eyes.